# What does the .numpy() function do?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

I tried searching for the documentation online but I can't find anything that gives me an answer. What does `.numpy()` function do? The example code given is:

```
y_true = []
for X_batch, y_batch in mnist_test:
    y_true.append(y_batch.numpy()[0].tolist())
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both in Pytorch and Tensorflow, the `.numpy()` method is pretty much straightforward. It converts a `tensor` object into an `numpy.ndarray` object. This implicitly means that the converted tensor will be now processed on the CPU.

Comment: > `This implicitly means that the converted tensor will be now processed on the CPU.`

Here's a [relevant docstring](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c256c071bb26e1e13b4666d1b3e229e110bc914a/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L1126-L1138) supporting this statement

Answer (score 2):

Ever getting a problem understanding some PyTorch function you may ask `help()`.

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
help(t.numpy)
```

Out:

```
Help on built-in function numpy:

numpy(...) method of torch.Tensor instance
    numpy() -> numpy.ndarray
    
    Returns :attr:`self` tensor as a NumPy :class:`ndarray`. This tensor and the
    returned :class:`ndarray` share the same underlying storage. Changes to
    :attr:`self` tensor will be reflected in the :class:`ndarray` and vice versa.
```

This [numpy()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) function is the converter form torch.Tensor to numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at this code below, we see a simple example where the `.numpy()` convert Tensors to numpy arrays automatically.

```
import numpy as np

ndarray = np.ones([3, 3])

print("TensorFlow operations convert numpy arrays to Tensors automatically")
tensor = tf.multiply(ndarray, 42)
print(tensor)


print("And NumPy operations convert Tensors to numpy arrays automatically")
print(np.add(tensor, 1))

print("The .numpy() method explicitly converts a Tensor to a numpy array")
print(tensor.numpy())
```

In the 2nd last line of code, we see that the tensorflow officials declared it as the converter of Tensor to a numpy array.
You may check it out [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics)